# How to add image and title to header of table view IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In table view I have created header.

What is the correct way to set image or title in tableView's header? What I need to do?

TIA

Comment: are you referring to header of section in tableView or a common header at top of the TableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

you need to create a `UIView` and add other views like `UIImageView`(for image), `UILabel`(for title) and return the `UIView` at last.

Comment: Image is adding now but its expanded for full headers, do we need to set height and width for that?

Comment: When creating your UIImageView initialize with the rect of your requirement. eg         
**UIImageView* imgView=[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)];**

Answer (score 8):

```
- (UIView *)tableView : (UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection : (NSInteger) section {

    UIImageView *imgVew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"]];
    return imgVew;
}
```

By this you can set image background for tableview section header!

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginHeader.png"];
   UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,100);

   return imageView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-big.png"];

    UIImageView * imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

    imgview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

    imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return imgview;


}
```